# Find a generic DbSet in a DbContext dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core

I know this question has already been asked but I couldn't find an answer that satisfied me. What I am trying to do is to retrieve a particular `DbSet<T>` based on its type's name.

I have the following :

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("MyDllAssemblyName")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("MyCallingAssemblyName")]

class MyDbContext : DbContext {

    public DbSet<ModelA> A { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ModelB> B { get; set; }

    public dynamic GetByName_SwitchTest(string name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "A": return A;
            case "B": return B;
        }
    }

    public dynamic GetByName_ReflectionTest(string fullname)
    {
        Type targetType = Type.GetType(fullname);
        var model = GetType()
            .GetRuntimeProperties()
            .Where(o => 
                o.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                o.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>) &&
                o.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Contains(targetType))
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (null != model)
            return model.GetValue(this);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have no trouble getting the type itself whether it is via a simple switch or reflection. I need however to return the type as a dynamic since I do not know what DbSet type it will be. 
Then somewhere else in the same assembly, I use it this way :

```
// MyDbContext MyDbContextInstance..
var model = MyDbContextInstance.GetByName_SwitchTest("A");
var record1 = model.FirstOrDefault(); // It crashes here with RunTimeBinderException
```

At this point `model` contains an instance of a `InternalDbSet<ModelA>` type. From there, any use I do with the `model` object I get a RunTimeBinderException :
    'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalDbSet' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'

Investigating on the web, I found a [blog post](http://www.heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/5/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic) explaining that (dixit his blog) :

> the reason the call to FirstOrDefault() fails is that the type
>   information of model is not available at runtime. The reason it's not
>   available is because anonymous types are not public. When the method
>   is returning an instance of that anonymous type, it's returning a
>   System.Object which references an instance of an anonymous type -  a
>   type whose info isn't available to the main program.

And then he points that a solution :

> The solution is actually quite simple. All we have to do is open up
>   AssemplyInfo.cs of the ClassLibrary1 project and add the following
>   line to it: `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("assembly-name")]`

I did try this solution on my code but it doesn't work. For info I have an asp.net 5 solution with two assemblies running on dnx dotnet46. An app and a dll containing all my models and DbContext. All the concerned calls I do are located on the dll though.

Does this solution have any chance to work ?
Am I missing something ?
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated ?

Thanks in advance

**[EDIT]**

I have tried to return `IQueryable<dynamic>` rather than `dynamic` and I could do the basic query `model.FirstOrDefault();` **but** above all I'd like to be able to filter on a field too :

```
var record = model.FirstOrDefault(item => item.MyProperty == true);
```

Comment: how about change the dynamic to IEnumerable<dynamic> ?

Comment: I did try something similar ( changed to IQueryable<dynamic> ) and even though I could do some queries like `model.FirstOrDefault()` it won't allow me to do things like `model.FirstOrDefault(item => item.MyProperty == true)`. which reduces the usefulness of the thing.

Comment: I have run into this same issue. Any chance that you have reached a resolution?

Comment: Hi @Asryael, unfortunately I haven't found a proper solution yet and by lack of time I had to come up with an alternative solution that works ok in my case scenario ( Posted below ). Hopefully this can help you out.

Comment: Does this not work `var mydbset= this.Set(typeof(SomeEntity));`

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer:** This response doesn't give a stricto sensu answer to my question. It is rather a different approach to resolve my own problem. I am aware this is a specific example for a given situation that will not work for everyone. I am posting this approach in the hope it helps someone but will not mark it as the answer as I am still hoping for a real solution.

To start with, let's accept the fact that the only useful information we can get out of the current code is whether a record exists or not.. Any attempt of a dynamic queries after that would give the RuntimeBinderException.

Then let's continue with another fact; DbContext.Add(object) and DbContext.Update(object) are not template based so we can use them to save our models ( Instead of db.A.Add() or db.A.Update() )

In my own situation, no more is required to work out a procedure

1. Define models a little differently

To start with, I need a field that is retrievable across all my models which should obviously be a way to identify a unique record.

```
// IModel give me a reliable common field to all my models ( Fits my DB design maybe not yours though )
interface IModel { Guid Id { get; set; } }

// ModelA inherit IModel so that I always have access to an 'Id'
class ModelA : IModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int OtherField { get; set; }
}

// ModelB inherit IModel so that I always have access to an 'Id'
class ModelB : IModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string WhateverOtherField { get; set; }
}
```

2. Re-purpose the dynamic queries a bit to do something we know works

I haven't found a way to do smart query dynamically, so instead I know I can reliably identify a record and know if it exists or not.

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext {

    public DbSet<ModelA> A { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ModelB> B { get; set; }

    // In my case, this method help me to know the next action I need to do
    // The switch/case option is not pretty but might have better performance 
    // than Reflection. Anyhow, this is one's choice.
    public bool HasRecord_SwitchTest(string name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "A": return A.AsNoTracking().Any(o => o.Id == id);
            case "B": return B.AsNoTracking().Any(o => o.Id == id);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // In my case, this method help me to know the next action I need to do
    public bool HasRecord_ReflectionTest(string fullname)
    {
        Type targetType = Type.GetType(fullname);
        var model = GetType()
            .GetRuntimeProperties()
            .Where(o => 
                o.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                o.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>) &&
                o.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Contains(targetType))
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (null != model)
            return (bool)model.GetValue(this).AsNoTracking().Any(o => o.Id == id);
        return false;
    }

    // Update and save immediately - simplified for example
    public async Task<bool> UpdateDynamic(object content)
    {
        EntityEntry entry = Update(content, GraphBehavior.SingleObject);
        return 1 == await SaveChangesAsync(true);
    }

    // Insert and save immediately - simplified for example
    public async Task<bool> InsertDynamic(object content)
    {
        EntityEntry entry = Add(content, GraphBehavior.SingleObject);
        return 1 == await SaveChangesAsync(true);
    }
}
```

3. A little bit of plumbing to give a sense to my situation

Next, what I needed to do with that dynamic queries was a way to replicate data from a server down to my client. ( I have omitted a big chunk of the architecture to simplify this example )

```
class ReplicationItem
{
    public ReplicationAction Action { get; set; } // = Create, Update, Delete
    public string ModelName { get; set; } // Model name
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // Unique identified across whole platform
}
```

4. Connecting the bits.

Now, here's the routine that connects the bits

```
public async void ProcessReplicationItem(ReplicationItem replicationItem)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        // Custom method that attempts to get remote value by Model Name and Id
        // This is where I get the strongly typed object 
        var remoteRecord = await TryGetAsync(replicationItem.ModelName, replicationItem.Id);
        bool hasRemoteRecord = remoteRecord.Content != null;

        // Get to know if a local copy of this record exists.
        bool hasLocalRecord = db.HasRecord_ReflectionTest(replicationItem.ModelName, replicationItem.Id);

        // Ensure response is valid whether it is a successful get or error is meaningful ( ie. NotFound )
        if (remoteRecord.Success || remoteRecord.ResponseCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            switch (replicationItem.Action)
            {
                case ReplicationAction.Create:
                {
                    if (hasRemoteRecord)
                    {
                        if (hasLocalRecord)
                            await db.UpdateDynamic(remoteRecord.Content);
                        else
                            await db.InsertDynamic(remoteRecord.Content);
                    }
                    // else - Do nothing
                    break;
                }
                case ReplicationAction.Update:
                    [etc...]
            }
        }
    }
}

// Get record from server and with 'response.Content.ReadAsAsync' type it 
// already to the appropriately
public static async Task<Response> TryGetAsync(ReplicationItem item)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.ModelName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Missing a model name", nameof(item));
    }

    if (item.Id == Guid.Empty)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Missing a primary key", nameof(item));
    }

    // This black box, just extrapolate a uri based on model name and id
    // typically "api/ModelA/{the-guid}"
    string uri = GetPathFromMessage(item);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:12345");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return new Response()
            {
                Content = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync(Type.GetType(item.ModelName)),
                Success = true,
                ResponseCode = response.StatusCode
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new Response()
            {
                Success = false,
                ResponseCode = response.StatusCode
            };
        }
    }
}

public class Response
{
    public object Content { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode ResponseCode { get; set; }
}
```

**ps:** I am still interested in a real answer, so please keep posting for other answer if you have a real one to share.

Answer (score 0):

So how did I do it when I am not aware of `<T>` during compile time.

First need to get the type as **DbContext.Set** method returns a non-generic DbSet instance for access to entities of the given type in the context and the underlying store.

```
public virtual DbSet Set(Type entityType)
```

Note here argument is the type of entity for which a set should be returned.And set for the given entity type is the return value.

```
var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == <Pass your table name>);
```

now once I have this type

```
if(type != null)
{
DbSet context = context.Set(type);
}
```

Or a one liner would be

```
DbSet mySet = context.Set(Type.GetType("<Your Entity Name>"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However - `public virtual DbSet Set(Type entityType)` - seems to no longer exist with Entity Framework 7. On top on that, `DbSet` wouldn't allow me to do fluent API queries on the models.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the DBSet for a specific type:

```
public object GetByType(DbContextcontext, Type type) {
     var methode = _context.GetType().GetMethod("Set", types: Type.EmptyTypes);
     if (methode == null) {
        return null;
     }
     return methode.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(_context, null);
}
```

Comment: You can extract the `MethodInfo` from a delegate instead of using reflection; `new Func<DbSet<object>>(_context.Set<object>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition()`. Which is a useful trick when a type has multiple overloads of the same method name.